# ErrorException in Laravel Undefined variable

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel and I am using Relations now, but I am getting an error as

> ErrorException :Undefined variable: users (View: D:\Softwares\WampServer\www\LaravelRelations\resources\views\users\index.blade.php)

**Controller is in** `usersController.php`

```
public function index()
{
    $users = \App\User::all();
    return view('users.index', compact($users));
}
```

**Route is defined in** `web.php`

```
Route::resource('users', 'usersController');
```

**Models are** `User.php` **and** `Role.php` **as**

```
<?php
//User.php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    public function role() {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Role');
    }
}


<?php
//Role.php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model
{
    public function user() {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\User');
    }
}
```

**and here's the** `index.blade.php` **in users folder as**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <?php
                foreach ($users as $user) {
                    echo "<li>" . $user->username . "is" . $user->role->role_name;
                }
            ?>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

The error is in this line `foreach ($users as $user) {` in `$users variable`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrong part of your code is `compact($users)` It must be `compact('users')`. Fixed code is

```
public function index()
{
    $users = \App\User::all();
    return view('users.index', compact('users');
}
```

**compact('users')** is equivalent **['users' => $users]**

Comment: Yeah! it worked like a charm and output came, but the role is not coming up username comes but the role in not coming can u see the error?
echo "<li>" . $user->username . "is" . $user->role->role_name;
in this line

Comment: your role table has role_name column, and can show role table structure??

Comment: in blade after foreach ($users as $user) { dd($user->toArray());, and show result

Comment: Yeah, I understand the error was in the column name there was only name not role_name now I changed that and worked, Thanks bro!
Must be accepted and again Thanks!

Comment: there's a typo in return view('users.index', compact('users'); should be return view('users.index', compact('users'));

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public function index()
{
    $users = \App\User::all();
    return view('users.index', ['users' => $users] );
}
```

Comment: The error was in compact($users) the $ sign I corrected that, Thanks for replying!