# laravel ErrorException Undefined variable: (after server change)

Tags: php, laravel, server, move

After moving script to another server - site stops working.

I'm not familiar with Laravel. Friend just ask me to make a server change. I've changed variables to connect to database, but site stops working with errors

> ErrorException in 1e73d8bdeb0c0b9afcce60440a41849556f6dc26.php line 55:
>   Undefined variable: any_current

I have deleted all files inside this cache folder - but they rebuilded and problem persists.

I've already checked if i assign an `''` to `$any_current` inside `index.php` if that helps - but no, there was another error then. After I edited `header.blade.php`and cut of these 3 lines:

I've moved debug information to static html file [here](https://noad.pl/stack/error.html)

Server move was from shared hosting to VPS (linux) - meyby I dont have some libraries ?

I found some solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51158554/errorexception-in-laravel-undefined-variable)

But this code was working on old server soI don't think so it is code related but `config/library` related.

I found someone said that solution was running some

```
php artisan config:cache
```

piece of code, but I've never used laravel and im not sure how to use it, my `vps` via `ssh` don't like it ;-)

Comment: Delete your config file under bootstrap > cache > config.php. Not sure but try it.

Comment: run `php artisan config:clear` after change in configuration and also run  `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: You have to connect via ssh, go to the project folder (you can be sure it is the project folder if you do `ls -l` and see all the laravel files), then run `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: i used this manual: https://tecadmin.net/install-laravel-on-debian-9-stretch/

steps 1-3 navigate into ssh to site folder then i can run php artisan config:clear and php artisan cache:clear
it outputs green: Configuration cache cleared and Cache cleared succesfully so i think i done it well. But after shift + F5 on website, problem persists.

Comment: if i delete line with $any_current from header.blade.php the error changes to: ErrorException in 341ed9a95c5164e324065439021bbbf8287b7dfb.php line 66:
Undefined index: groupClass

Comment: @Aksen P run php artisan view:clear i think its loading old views. on manually delete all files from storage\framework\views\

Comment: Or somehow the value of $some_subfolder is not being set.

Comment: I already cleared storage\framework\views\ few times, files always reappear with same names. (its that correct ?!) 

i also used composer update - no changes.

Its looks like probably some part of code is not done, but how ?! and do not create needed variables, mby becouse of other directory structure ? 

Where i should check to confirm that ?

i already used any display errors / debug config and nothing more shows up.